# how to solve discontinuous line when drawing with python

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
drawing = False

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
  global ix,iy,drawing

  if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    drawing= True
    ix,iy=x,y
  elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
    if drawing == True:
      cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,(0,0,0),-1)
  elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    drawing == False

img=np.ones((512,512,3),np.uint8)*255
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(True):
  cv2.imshow('image',img)

  if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xff == ord('q'):
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The first line was drawn slowly, the 2nd one was drawn fast:

[image: the first line was drawn slowly, the 2nd one was drawn fast]

My questions are :

1. what is it that cause this problem?
2. how to solve it.

Comment: Why would you expect there not to be any gaps? You are drawing a circle at a series of discrete points. You need to write some code to 'join the dots' - draw a line from the last point to the current one.

Comment: I know im drawing a series of discrete points, but due to the program and result, it seems like it draws a circle per tick. and as long as the speed of drawing a circle is faster than the moving speed of mouse, it should be continuous, because each circle should have overlapping part in my opinion.

Comment: And that's precisely what is happening. When you draw the line slowly they overlap, fast and they don't. You should investigate Abdul's answer, below, more thoroughly. It's almost exactly what I was going to post.

Comment: @wypxhh123 There are gaps because a new mouse event is raised before the previous circle is drawn when you move fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `circle`, when you use `circle`, on fast movements there will be gaps. There will be gaps because a new mouse event is raised before the previous circle is drawn when you move fast. Use `line` instead as follows:

```
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
 global ix,iy,drawing

 if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
   drawing= True
   ix,iy=x,y
 elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
   if drawing:
     cv2.line(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(0,0,0), 3)
     ix,iy = x,y
 elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
   drawing == False
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i found there are still gaps. And i still dont understand why there are gaps. There is no reason to be discontinuous according to the program.

Comment: There are no gaps when I used the above method. Can you show your result?

Comment: @wypxhh123 I updated the answer with a reason. Hope this helps. Please mark as answer if it helped. :)

Comment: I copied your code, but result is still no good.  Result: http://imgur.com/KTWIaoK

Comment: It appears like you're still drawing circles.